# Subscript out of bounds, stopping for loop at the last value

Tags: r, for-loop

I keep getting the error:

```
Error in locoh[[i + 1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I'm almost certain that its because my its looking for the additional value so `length(locoh) +1`, but that value does not exist. How could I stop this `for` loop at the max extent of my object locoh?

```
# Estimate overlap between LoCoHs for each 10-day interval
for (i in 1:(length(locoh))){
  hr_overlap(locoh[[i]], locoh[[i+1]], type = 'hr')
}
```

For example, I would my for loop to start from the first value in `locoh, then locoh+1, locoh + 2, .....` then stop once it reaches `locoh_max value`. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loop to the `length`, it should be to `length(locoh)-1` because `locoh[[i+1]]` at the last `i` i.e. `length` will be out of bounds

```
for (i in 1:(length(locoh)-1)){
   hr_overlap(locoh[[i]], locoh[[i+1]], type = 'hr')
 }
```